# Date inputs cannot be aligned right on iOS7

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, ios7

**tl;dr, Here the test, iOS7 can't right-align date inputs:** http://cdpn.io/dxjHy

Consider this HTML:

```html
<input type="date" id="test">
```

And this CSS:

```css
#test {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;

  text-align:right;
  padding:30px;
  width:400px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Safari on iOS7 doesn't want to right-align the text in the date input. My opinion is that Chrome's interpretation is the correct one. Any ideas on how to make Safari cooperate?

Chrome 30:

[image: Chrome]

Safari Mobile on iOS7, iPad:

[image: iOS7]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a solution that works great. This seems to be the culprit, in Safari's stylesheet of `input[type=date]`

```
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
```

Add this to your CSS...

```
input[type=date] {
    display:block;
    -webkit-appearance:button;
    -moz-appearance:button;
    appearance:button;
}
```

...and now your input will be able to understand `text-align:right;` correctly.

Comment: The key is `display: block`.

Comment: Good call - ignore the ```appearance: button``` - its unrelated and adds unwanted styling

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem in my office, we made a workaround.

```
<div> 
    <input type="date" id="test">
</div>
```

and for the css

```
div{
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}
input[type="date"]{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    right:0;
}
```

Hope, it can help you.

Comment: It's a great workaround, but you need to insert markup for presentational purposes. Also, you would need to style the `div` the same way you styled your `input type="date"` to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Hoshibe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996610/hoshibe) css trick did help but had to Add "left: 0;" to center the input box and not have overflow.

```
div{
    position:relative;
    width: 99%; <!--Can be any width you need.-->
}
input[type="date"]{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    right:0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then Adding below code to input[type="date"] will right align the text.

```
text-align: right;
display: block;
```

This fixed the issue in iOS 7 and 8.